# SBT ignores http.nonProxyHosts

Tags: sbt

I'm trying to get sbt not to use a proxy when publishing an artifact. All documentation seems to point to setting the following when starting sbt:

```
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="localhost|*.xxx"
```

but doesn't work. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803459/how-to-use-sbt-from-behind-proxy) details how to set a proxy but not how to ignore it. Also tried setting:

```
SBT_OPTS='http.nonProxyHosts="localhost|*.xxx"'
```

and

```
JAVA_OPTS='http.nonProxyHosts="localhost|*.xxx"'
```

And also escaped the pipe ("localhost\|*.xxx"). Found the [issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1852) unresolved on sbt's github page.

Any clues appreciated.
Thanks.

Edited - here is the full command:

```
java -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="localhost\|*.xxx"  -jar {PATH_TO_SBT_JAR}/sbt-launch.jar clean packagedArtifacts publish
```

Comment: Potentially related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902830/jvm-arguments-for-https-nonproxyhosts